# WPF copy-able Label or TextBox that looks like a Label

Tags: wpf

What I really want is a Label that I can select with my cursor and copy-and-paste from.

But I'm told elsewhere on the web that that's not possible so instead I should use a TextBox and give it the appearance and behavior of a Label.

I'd settle for a textbox where there's no "box" with a 3D effect, and which is not editable by the user; i.e., he can't type anything into it.  I do not want it to be "grey'ed out".

I only need one, so I'd like to keep this simple and just use the available attributes, and avoid creating an elaborate custom control that I will only instantiate once.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Can you do a read-only textbox and set the borderbrush to transparant and borderthickness to zero?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to answer my own question but I worked it out for myself so I didn't want anyone else to waste their time

I made the TextBox readonly but also made the caret visible to I could select it.   I gave it a border of 0 all around and sert the background color to match the background color of the rest of the app.

> ```
>                 <TextBox Text=" " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="758,382,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="labelVRetY"
>                        Width="80" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"  IsReadOnly="True"
>                        IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True" Background="#FFF0F0F0" />
> ```

Comment: Maybe it's better to make background transparent? In case you change the background of the window.